# Is it possible to rewrite the outcome of 2*func(x) to be func(x) + func(x) in Python?

Tags: python

This problem has been intriguing, even though it's not necessarily neat.
I have the following code:

```
import random

def d(m):
    return random.randint(1, m)

print(3*d(6))
```

This will print the returned value of d(6) and multiply that by 3. What I would like to have is to define a set of symbols so I can set that 3*d(6) will instead return: d(6) + d(6) + d(6). Alternatively is it possible to set the expression '3d6' to return what I want in a general case for XdY?

Is this solvable with wrappers / addition of symbols or do I have to go deeper and change stuff in the interpreter?

I'm trying to make the program read more naturally for the gaming genre.  In tabletop gaming, people say "2d6", which means 'throw two 6-sided dice'.  This has a different probability density function compared to 2*d(6).

Comment: You can use a generator expression, which creates a for loop. `sum(d(6) for _ in range(2))`.

Comment: Make a class and define its `__mul__` and other necessary methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have `3*d(6)` produce the effect of `d(6)+d(6)+d(6)` *and* have `d(6)` return an int. If you were creating objects representing probability distributions or something like that, you could overload `__rmul__` the way you want, but not with ints.

You can't have `3d6` evaluate to what you want either. `3d6` is not a valid Python token. You would have to alter and recompile the Python source code to produce your own Python variant with altered syntax, and it'd be a lot of work with little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a function call that returns an integer, but you could manage something similar with a class. The class can define a `__mul__` method that implements multiplication in any way it wants.

Here's a possible way to do it, where the `d` class is an object representing the abstract die roll (not a specific result), and you can roll the die by calling the instance:

```
class d:
    def __init__(self, sides, count=1, offset=0):
        self.sides = sides
        self.count = count
        self.offset = offset

    def __mul__(self, num):
        return d(self.sides, self.count*num, self.offset*num)
    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def __add__(self, num):
        return d(self.sides, self.count, self.offset + num)
    __radd__ = __add__

    def __call__(self):
        return sum(random.randint(1, self.sides) for _ in range(self.count)) + self.offset
```

Use:

```
x = 3*d(6) + 4
print(x()) # prints a number between 7 and 22 (with 14-15 being the most common)
```

Comment: This can be generalized further to operations like `3*d(6) + 4*d(4) + d(12)` by storing lists of dice and multiplicities instead of just single sides and count numbers, or by storing a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking to redefine language elements, which would require altering the parser and action rules.  Yes, you can define a class and override the basic operations, but I fear that you'll get yourself into some untenable language situations.  `3d6` requires re-engineering Python; `3*d(6)` allows your class to take over, if carefully designed, but is still fraught with traps for you.  Since you had to ask this question in the first place ...

Instead, you should be thinking about how to program simple routines to do what you want with the given input.  For instance, you might want a function

```
def roll(d_str):
```

which could take string input such as "3d6", "d20 + 1", and "2d8 + d10".  It would then perform the requested random generation and return the result of the roll as a simple integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class and overload the * and + operations.

```
class D:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return sum(self.roll() for _ in range(other))
        return NotImplemented

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, D):
            return self.roll() * other.roll()
        return self.roll() * other

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.roll() + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other
```

Then you can do various arithmetic with D objects with this behaviour.

```
>>> D(6) * D(6)  # roll two dice and multiply the results
10
>>> [3 * D(6) for n in range(20)]  # roll 3d6 20 times.
[8, 11, 12, 11, 16, 9, 11, 17, 6, 12, 8, 14, 9, 11, 13, 7, 11, 17, 8, 13]
```

If you want to roll a single die, you must either use the `roll()` method or multiply by 1.

```
>>> 1*D(6)
4
```

Note that since `__mul__` and `__rmul__` are different, there's a different behaviour, depending on whether the D object is on the right or left side of the operator.

```
>>> D(6) * 10  # rolls a single d6 and multiplies by 10
40
>>> 10 * D(6)  # rolls 10 d6 and add the results
33
>>> 2 * D(6) * 100  # rolls two dice and multiply the sum by 100
700
```

To get closer to the syntax you want, you can create D objects and call them `d4`, `d6` etc. A new random number will be generated each time you use a + or * operation on the name die.

```
>>> d4, d10, d20 = D(6), D(10), D(20)
>>> 2*d4 + d20 + 7
32
>>> 1*d20, 1*d20, 1*d20
(19, 3, 12)
```

See the python docs on [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for further explanation of these special operator methods.